# Java JPS tool not working

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to use the JPS tool (Java Process Monitoring Tool)

I have Oracle jdk1.6 on my ubuntu-12.04 machine
My Configuration.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_39"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_39-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode)


$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/java:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_39

$ cat /etc/environment 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_39"

$ jps
The program 'jps' can be found in the following packages:
 * openjdk-6-jdk
 * openjdk-7-jdk
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I want to use oracle-jdk not open-jdk.

Answer (score 2):

use this command

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_39/bin
```

And then try `jps` command in the same shell.

Comment: i already have my java path in PATH variable. but JPS is not working . I edited  both PATH variable in .profile file and /etc/environment.

Comment: Do u have JAVA_HOME/bin in your PATH. That is required because jps resides in JAVA_HOME/bin not JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 2):

If you have exported the java/bin path in your .bashrc, then try to reload the .bashrc file 
type

> $> cd $HOME
>
> $> . .bashrc

and then try to echo the Path. It should include the java/bin folder.

> $> echo $PATH

it should solve the problem

Comment: i already have my java path in PATH variable. but JPS is not working

Comment: is it the JAVA_HOME or the PATH variable. the PATH variable should have an entry of JAVA_HOME/bin
Try echo $PATH

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problems like yours. At first I have had Java 1.7 installed on my machine, then I installed Java 1.6.

When I check inside this folder, I found no `jps`

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin
```

So I uninstall Java 1.7 (through Synaptic Package Manager), and re-install Java 1.6 again. After that, I can see `jps` inside `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin` folder. And I can use `jps` again.

I hope that it'll help. This is my first answer in Stack Overflow, so please do not vote down.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a shell alias in `/etc/profile` after environment variables:

```
alias jps='/usr/jdk/bin/jps'
```

it works now.